# Java ThreadPoolExecutor stops working after a while

Tags: java, concurrency, threadpool, executor

I have a problem with the ThreadPoolExecutor. It works fine for hours, but sometimes (at a random time, sometimes after 2 minutes or 3 hours) it stops executing the submitted tasks and the program hangs.

The queue is full and all corethreads are active at this time.

I simply don't know where this is coming from. Especially because it sometimes works for 3 hours while all corethreads are working all the time.

If there is anybody who has a suggestion for me, I would be very happy.

Comment: That's a deadlock. So what code is shared between threads? redneck debugging: Try running your app in debug mode and wait till it locks, connect with a debugger and suspend the jvm, you can then see at which point all your threads are.

Comment: If you suspect a deadlock then dump all the threads' stack trace. On Windows this is done by pressing Control-Break. Look to see what the threads have synchronized on and what they are waiting on.

Comment: Happening to a client of mine in 7u45, using `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`, after several hours of use for no clear reason. Nothing out of the ordinary in a thread dump; all threads in the pool are idle. Plenty of `ScheduledFutureTask`s with `time`s well in the past are in the queue.

Answer (score 1):

Take a [look at the stack dump.](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/stack.html) This will tell you if the threads are in some blocking operation, waiting for a condition that never happens, working, or truly deadlocked.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with a code that do I/O operations downloading web pages. At some point, sometimes, in minutes or hours, a thread hangs doing some I/O operation and stop to work.

If this is your case, set an abortion time.

Run your code in a debugger and when your application stop, see what were the last methods that your threads executed.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a memory leak somewhere and that is causing the lock after a few hours

Answer (score 0):

It might be related to https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6822370 if you were using an older version of the JVM. This was fixed in 6u18. See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/6u18-142093.html